# Form is not being submitted in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am trying to save data to a table, but it is supposed to  submit if everything is good

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const formm = document.querySelector('#CreateAccount')
const school = document.querySelector('#skool');
const username = document.querySelector('#username');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');
const pwd = document.querySelector('#password');
const conf = document.querySelector('#confpassword');

formm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    validateForm();
    if(result == true){
        formm.submit();
        console.log(2);
    }else{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(30);
    }
    console.log(30);
});


function isFormValid(){
    const inputscontainers = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs')
    let result=true;
    inputscontainers.forEach((container) => {
        if(container.classList.contains("error")){
            return false;
    }})
    return result;
}
function validateForm(){
    if(username.value.trim() == ''){
        setError(username, 'Name cannot be empty');
    }else if(username.value.trim() < 5){
        setError(username, 'Idrc');
        console.log(3);
    }
    else{
        setSuccess(username);
    }
    if(email.value.trim() == ''){
        setError(email, 'You forgot to fill in your email.');
    }
    else if(isEmailValid(email.value)){
        setSuccess(email);
    }else{
        setError(email, "Provide a valid email");
    }
    if(pwd.value.trim()==''){
        setError(pwd, "Password can't be empty");
    }else if(pwd.value.trim().length<6 || pwd.value.trim().length>20){
        setError(pwd, 'Length must be minimum 6 characters and max 20.');
    }else{
        setSuccess(pwd);
    }
    if(conf.value.trim() == ''){
       setError(conf, 'This is an empty password');
    }else if(conf.value !== pwd.value){
        setError(conf, 'Passwords dont match');
    }
    else{
        setSuccess(conf);
    }
        
        
    
}

function setError(elementr, errorMessage){
    const parents = elementr.parentElement;
    parents.classList.add("error");
    parents.classList.remove("success");
    const paragraph = parents.querySelector('p').textContent = errorMessage;
}

function setSuccess(elementr){
     const parents = elementr.parentElement;
    parents.classList.add("success");
    parents.classList.remove("error");
}
    
function isEmailValid(email){
    const reg =/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    return reg.test(email);
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="CreateAccount" action="techer.php" method="GET">
<div class="main">
<div class="Title">
<h1>Enter your details.</h1>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
<label for="skool">SchoolName:</label>
<input type="text" id="skool" placeholder ="Put the school name" name="skool"></input>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
<p>Error Message</p>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder ="Username" name="username">
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
<p id="p">Error Message</p>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder =" Password" name="password"></input>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
<p id="p">Error Message</p>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
<label for="confpassword">Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" id="confpassword" placeholder =" Confirm Password" name="confpassword"></input>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
<p>Error Message</p>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder ="Email" name="email"></input>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
<p>Error Message</p>
</div>
<button class="submitbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

As far as the eye can see, there are no errors, and it is not saving data to my php database, which is worrying. My expected result is for, when everything is correct, the from to be submitted then redirected to a php file! But what is happening, even if everything in the form is correct, it wont submit. Please HELP!!

Comment: `if(result == true)` there is no variable `result`.  Also, you don't seem to call `isFormValid` anywhere.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the request sent properly? Please check at least whether Javascript or PHP are responsible for the problem, and remove the tags that are not relevant for your problem (like: CSS)

Comment: You made a simple form validation total complex, your code can be optimized further to make it more simpler,  `const result = validateForm();` and you are not calling `isFormValid()` anywhere. and why are you adding classes on validation I recommend to just directly validate and submit the form in 1 function,

Comment: @MohammedKhurram, @Nico Haase, @James, i did all your suggestion:
```form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
 const result = validateForm();
    isFormValid();
    if(isFormValid==true){
        form.submit();
  console.log(3);
    }else {
        event.preventDefault();
  console.log(31);
    }
});``` correct

Answer (score 0):

Try adding, at the end of validateForm function:

```
return isFormValid();
```

then in your submit listener, change

```
validateForm();
```

to

```
let result = validateForm();
```